Component define custom constants
In a component what is the best or approved way to define constant values to be accessible throughout the component. Not language strings but numeric and other values.
Currently I have a defines.php file located in the admin/src/Extension folder and a require_once defines.php line at the top of the MycomComponent.php file above the class.
This seems to work ok with the defined values available throughout the component and only one file to edit if they need changing or adding to. But is there a "better" way?

For personnal constant values, I used regular labs re-replacer. It is not very some constant but I used it as Constants manager into then whole website
